# Why are items for other users on the TFS current iteration task board grey?

Tags: tfs, kanban, tfs-web-access

We are using TFS 2013 and for some users their items are in color on the task board and everyone elses are grey and the line for others is collapsed. The permissions for all users are the same. Anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Person" drop-down in the upper-right corner. If "All" is selected then all rows will be expanded and all items will have color. If a specific person is selected only their row will be expanded and all items assigned to others will be grey.